# Windows Forms: writing to a RichTextBox from another file (C++)

Tags: c++, winforms, pointers, richtextbox

How can I enter text in a richTextBox from outside the forms class?

I have four files within my project:
Form1.h
Form1.cpp
Main.cpp
Importfile.cpp

inside form1.cpp I use the function:

```
System::Void Form1::SendText_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    info_function();
}
```

inside Importfile.cpp I am trying to write the text using the following code:

```
#include "Form1.h"
#include "Importfile.h"

using namespace Forms_test; // the namespace where my Form class is in

void info_function()
{   
    //Form1->richTextBox1.AppendText("Starting slaveinfo\n");
    //formpointer->richTextBox1->AppendText("Starting slaveinfo\n");
    //richTextBox1->AppendText("Starting slaveinfo\n");
    // I tried all three.
}
```

Inside my main file I start the form like this:

```
Application::EnableVisualStyles();
Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 

Form1^ formpointer = (gcnew Form1());
Application::Run(formpointer);
```

I do this so I can maybe use the formpointer somehow to get to my richtextbox.

My problem is, when i try to build I get the error: "left of '->AppendText' must point to class/struct/union/generic type"

I'm thinking that somehow it can't find my richTextBox pointer but how can I make sure it can? I know there probably have been more questions somewhat like this but somehow I can't seem to find them.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You're trying to break object encapsulation. Pass your text through a public function in `Form1`, instead.